# Day and time of most visitors

Tags: google-analytics

For a client of ours, we're looking for a matrix from the Google Analytics reports that shows the best day and time with the most visitors on the website, measured by page views.
I've been inspired by SocialBro, which shows this awesome grid with dots indicating the best time to tweet, depending on how many of your followers are active at a given time.

Is it possible to generate such a view with Google Analytics custom reports?

Really looking forward to any suggestions!

Image attached with SocialBro layout.

[image: Socialbro layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the hourly traffic breakdown from Twitter as a table easy enough [example here](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253Ahour&metrics=ga%253Avisits&filters=ga%253Asource%253D~twitter&sort=ga%253Ahour&start-date=2013-03-03&end-date=2013-03-16&max-results=50). On the visualisation front, will have to be a case of roll-your-own.